# ArrayAdapter fails in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

Hy, I am new to android and I am trying to build a ListView inside a fragment. I have a main class `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener` and a few inner classes.
I am using a `public class PopulatePageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter` to return the fragment i need, and a class representing my fragment:

```
public class usersList extends Fragment {
    private List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
        populateUsernameList();

        ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Log.d("Q","QQ");
        list.setAdapter(adapter);//here my app fails
        Log.d("Q","WW");
        return rootView;
    }
```

This is my ArrayAdapter

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contact_layout, usersList);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View userView = convertView;
            if (userView == null) {
                userView = MainMenuActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, parent, false);
            }

            User user = usersList.get(position);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) userView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(user.getProfilePictureId());

            TextView textView = (TextView) userView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCompleteName);
            textView.setText(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
            return userView;
        }
    }
```

I am thinking that I am not using right the ArrayAdapter but I dont see any other way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't parse your data (userList) to your adapter. Maybe take a look at this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

You have to attach your data to you adapter and parse your context as well:

```
ArrayList<User> usersList;
Context mContext;
public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> myListViewData) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.usersList = myListViewData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data to your adapter

```
ArrayList<Data> data=new ArrayList<Data>();
data= getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("data");
 adapter = new DataAdapter(getActivity(),data);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```